# Strange Behavior with MPMoviePlayerController When Programmatically Changing Volume

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod, volume

In my application I am changing volume using the MPMoviePlayerController volume property (for fade effects and muting while leaving it still playing).

Sometimes, sporadically, when changing the volume, the volume display (what you see when you use the volume buttons on the side of the iphone) will flash and disappear. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question ?

Comment: How are you programatically changing the volume?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.
I am using MPVolumeView in a view and a MPMoviePlayerController in another view.
When I allocate MPMoviePlayerController an play a video then return to my audio player using MPVolumeView the volume is displayed but not before using MPMoviePlayerController.

Thierry